# Redefine BOOST_FOREACH macro safely

Tags: c++, boost, boost-foreach

I have the following macro:

```
#define FOREACH(decl, c) BOOST_FOREACH(decl, std::make_pair((c).begin(), (c).end()))
```

(I am using this macro, because my containers do not implement the mutable iteration API.)

The problem with it, is that `c` is evaluated twice.

My question is can this macro be fixed so that:

1. `c` is evaluated at most once
2. Any local variables created in order to satisfy the first condition live within the respective foreach scope only.

Comment: It's best to avoid this sort of macro hackery and use the iteration statements (or algorithm function templates) when you want to iterate.

Comment: @mark, Does it have to be strict C++03. Would you allow g++ specific extensions, for example?

Comment: @Aaron - I use VS2010. So g++ specifics are off scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an inline helper function.

```
#define FOREACH(decl, c) BOOST_FOREACH(decl, pair_helper(c))

template <typename T>
inline std::pair<typename T::iterator, typename T::iterator> pair_helper (T c) {
    return std::make_pair(c.begin(), c.end());
}
```

Comment: Since the second `c` is an honest variable, you can omit those extra parentheses (unless you're some sort of RIAA agent).

Comment: You're right, I just copy pasted it from the given macro. Fixed

Comment: On VS2010 I had to add `typename` qualifications to the pair template arguments, but otherwise it has worked just fine. Thanks.

Comment: You're right, it is a requirement for specifying types within templates. Fixed

Answer (score 6):

There is no need for this hackery. Boost.Foreach relies on Boost.Range in order to retrieve the iterators. Which there are two ways to extend that:

1. Provide member functions and a nested type: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/extending/method_1.html
2. Provide free-standing functions and specialize metafunctions: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/extending/method_2.html

Now in your case, it looks like you provide the `begin()` and `end()` member functions, but don't provide the nested type `iterator`(I assume thats what you mean by the mutable iteration API). You can do one of two things.

First, you can `typedef` the nested iterator type like this:

```
typedef const_iterator iterator;
```

Secondly, if you can't modify the class, you can specialize the metafunctions, like this(replacing YourContainer with whatever your container type is):

```
namespace boost
{
    //
    // Specialize metafunctions. We must include the range.hpp header.
    // We must open the 'boost' namespace.
    //

    template< >
    struct range_mutable_iterator< YourContainer >
    {
        typedef YourContainer::const_iterator type;
    };

    template< >
    struct range_const_iterator< YourContainer >
    {
        typedef YourContainer::const_iterator type;
    };

} // namespace 'boost'
```

Of course I assume you have a `const_iterator` `typedef`'d in your class(Since you said it doesn't support mutable). If you don't, you will need to replace `YourContainer::const_iterator` with whatever type your `const_iterator` is.

Answer (score 2):

'Statement-expressions' are a [gcc/g++ extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) to avoid repeated evaluation of macro arguments

```
#define make_pair_of_iterators(c) ({typeof(c)& c_ = (c); make_pair(c_.begin(), c_.end()); })
```

Then you could do:

```
#define FOREACH(decl, c) BOOST_FOREACH(decl, make_pair_of_iterators(c) )
```

(And `typeof` is a gcc/g++ extension also.)